Groups of order $2^n p$ for $n\geq 1$ and $p$ prime with $2^n> (p-1)!$ are non-simple. Is my proof correct?
I'm doing my homework in Group Theory and as part of an exercise, I want to show the following Lemma:
Let $n\geq 1$, $p$ a prime, s.t. $2^n > (p-1)!$ and $G$ a group of order $2^n p$. Then G has a non-trivial normal subgroup.
Proof. The number $s_2$ of Sylow-$2$-subgroups is a divisor of $p$ (by Sylow III). If $s_2=1$, we are finished, because this subgroup would be normal. Assume $s_2 = p$. Then there is a transitive group action of $G$ on the Sylow-$2$-subgroups $\mathcal Q :=\{Q_i\}_{i=1}^p$ of $G$, i.e. a homomorphism
$$
\varphi: G\rightarrow \mathrm{Sym}(\mathcal Q)\cong S_p.
$$
Because of $2^n>(p-1)!$, we have $|G|>p!$ and by the pidgeon hole principle $\phi$ is not injective, hence it has a non-trivial kernel $\ker\phi\triangleleft G$. This conludes the proof.
Does this look correct? Thanks for your advice! :)
I wonder how $\varphi$ could be defined. Is
$$
\phi(g) = \sigma \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad \forall i: gP_ig^{-1} = P_{\sigma(i)}
$$
valid, because all Sylow-$2$-subgroups are conjugate?


Yes. 2) Yes.


Thank you so much :)
